# how to create a new row with a counted points in postgis

Tags: postgis, sql

I have two tables in `postgis` (pgadmin). In one table there are `points` and in the other table there are `polygons`(provinces). The tables are both over the same location (Netherlands). I want to count the points who are in every province and I want to export them to a row in the polygon (maybe a new table). **Summarized**: I want from every province the points counted in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the points and polygons are in the same projection (same SRID):

Add a column to the provinces table to store point counts:

```
ALTER TABLE provinces ADD COLUMN count_pts int;
```

Update the column with point counts:

```
UPDATE provinces SET count_pts = 
(SELECT ct FROM 
    (SELECT gid, count(gid) AS ct FROM
        (SELECT pts.pts_id AS id, provinces.gid AS gid FROM pts,provinces 
        WHERE st_intersects(pts.geom,provinces.geom)) a 
    GROUP BY gid) b
WHERE provinces.gid = b.gid);
```

Note that if a point fell in multiple polygons (this could be the case if polygons overlapped one another) if would be counted in both polygons.